# How to iterate over particular keys in a dict to get values

Tags: python

I have a large list containing many dictionaries. Within each dictionary I want to iterate over 3 particular keys and then dump into a new list. The keys are the same for each dict.

For example, I'd like to grab keys c, d, e from all the dicts in List below, output to List2.

```
List = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6...},
        {'a':10, 'b':20, 'c':30, 'd':40, 'e':50, 'f':60...},
        {'a':100, 'b':200, 'c':300, 'd':400, 'e':500, 'f':600...},]

List2 = [{'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5},
         {'c':30, 'd':40, 'e':50},
         {'c':300, 'd':400, 'e':500}]
```

Comment: It seems that working with `pandas` `DataFrame` would be convenient for something like this, each dict keys would be column names, and values rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a nested dict comprehension:

```
keys = ('c', 'd', 'e')
[{k: d[k] for k in keys} for d in List]
```

If those keys *may* be missing, you can use a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) ([`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) in Python 2, [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) in Python 3) to find an intersection to only include keys that are actually present:

```
keys = {'c', 'd', 'e'}
[{k: d[k] for k in d.viewkeys() & keys} for d in List]
```

Demo:

```
>>> List = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6},
...         {'a':10, 'b':20, 'c':30, 'd':40, 'e':50, 'f':60},
...         {'a':100, 'b':200, 'c':300, 'd':400, 'e':500, 'f':600}]
>>> keys = ('c', 'd', 'e')
>>> [{k: d[k] for k in keys} for d in List]
[{'c': 3, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}, {'c': 30, 'e': 50, 'd': 40}, {'c': 300, 'e': 500, 'd': 400}]
>>> List = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6},
...         {'a':10, 'b':20, 'c':30, 'd':40, 'f':60},
...         {'a':100, 'b':200, 'e':500, 'f':600}]
>>> keys = {'c', 'd', 'e'}
>>> [{k: d[k] for k in d.viewkeys() & keys} for d in List]
[{'e': 5, 'd': 4}, {'c': 30, 'd': 40}, {'e': 500}]
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn for the fast response, worked perfectly. I also tried Rafael's answer but could not get it to work. I don't understand nested dict comprehension yet, it is really efficient... I am new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
keys = ['c', 'd']  
for dictionary in List1:
        d = {}
        for key in dictionary:
            if key in keys:
                d[key] = dictionary[key]
        List2.append(d)
```

Comment: Why loop over the larger number of dictionary keys here rather than the smaller `keys` sequence? Also, testing for a key in a dictionary is O(1) constant cost vs. the O(N) cost of testing against a list, so you are picking the worst of performance options by looping over the dictionary here.